# Trouble with passing an ArrayList from Spring MVC action to JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, arraylist, jstl

I'm trying to pass a list of objects of the type User from my Spring MVC action to the JSP.

Here's what the User class looks like:

```
public class User {

    String name = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here's the Spring MVC action method:

```
@RequestMapping("/search.htm")
public String searchUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
        @ModelAttribute("userSearchResult") ArrayList<User> usersSearchResult) {
    usersSearchResult.add(new User()) ;
    usersSearchResult.get(0).setName("name1") ;
    System.out.println(usersSearchResult.get(0).getName()) ;
    System.out.println(user.getName());
    return "search" ;
}
```

Here's the JSP code:

```
<br/>
-----------------------<br/>
SEARCH RESULTS<br/>
-----------------------<br/>
#Results Shown: ${fn:length(userSearchResult)}
<br/>

<c:forEach items="${usersSearchResult}" var="auser">
    <br/>
    ------------<br/>
    ${auser.name}<br/>
    ------------<br/>
    <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

The length function correctly returns the value 1, but auser.name doesn't display anything.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `usersSearchResult` in the `<c:forEach>` tag, and `userSearchResult` for the length.

IMO it should just be `users`; it's a list of users. The context is implied.

Comment: Thank Dave, it was such a dumb mistake :D